# PHP Form builder class working with old version of bootstrap?

Tags: php, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the php form builder class (http://www.imavex.com/pfbc3.x-php5/examples/html5.php)
and jqbootstrapvalidation (http://reactiveraven.github.io/jqBootstrapValidation/)

So far I can succesfully combine these (even using some of the patterns php form builder class already built in) and I edited some of the element php files to change a pattern here and there, and to add some \n's to make a readable source code. (I still don't like my entire form on a single line in the source..)

But I would like to use different colours for the bootstrap. I've tried downloading several themed bootstrap.min.css files using paintstrapand twitter bootstrap themeroller

However, as soon as I include these instead of the standard netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css file, all my styling is lost and it looks the same as if there was no stylesheet included.

Since the php form builder class is relatively old, do I need to change all it's code to become compatible with the newer bootstrap, or is there a faster way to do this (perhaps a different form builder?)? Or am I messing up something else that is causing this change style options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appearantly there are a few changes need to make to fix this:
https://code.google.com/p/php-form-builder-class/issues/detail?id=205

allthough it is not "full-on" bootstrap 3.0. Also, the jqueryvalidator needs some adaptation to work with bootstrap 3.0. I'm currently busy making everything work the way I like it, adding glyphicons for the forms (optionally) etcetera. I'll get back to you as soon as I am finished and drop the code of somewhere for all the lovely people to enjoy or shout at.

Answer (score 0):

I did'nt want to use imavex class for several reasons :

- wanted a class witch could be easily updated if Bootstrap's version changed
- wanted to have more control on generated code (add or remove wrappers, class, attributes, ...)
- wanted to generate separate code for css/js includes/js code
- wanted to be able to configure any jquery plugin with it

So I made my own (not free but only 5$), you can see the demo and complete doc here : http://codecanyon.net/item/php-form-class-for-bootstrap/8790160?WT.ac=category_thumb&WT.z_author=migli

Hope it helps and hope you'll like it